# How to read exactly the message length in pipe?

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I am making a program where a child reads a message from a pipe written by the parent. But the question is: is it possible that the child starts reading in the pipe BEFORE that the parent has finished writing in it? If so, the child will read a fragment of the message and will terminate. How can I make sure that all the message will be read without reading char by char and looping while there are chars?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TEXT_LENGTH 20

int main(void) {
    int p[2];
    char msg[TEXT_LENGTH];

    if (pipe(p) == -1) {
        perror("Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    switch (fork()) {
        case -1:
            perror("Error");
            exit(1);
        case 0:
            close(p[1]);
            read(p[0], &msg, TEXT_LENGTH);
            printf("%s\n", msg);
            exit(0);
        default:
            close(p[0]);
            strcpy(msg, "Very long text ...\0");
            write(p[1], &msg, TEXT_LENGTH);
            wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Right now it works, but if the text is very long, will the parent have the time to write to it before the child enters the read?

Comment: If there is nothing to read, the reader will *block*. And: both read and write are *atomic* (at least, upto one buffer length)

Comment: I think pipes don't let you read from them until they're marked as closed.

Comment: Look up TLV (type, length, value) encoding.  Use it.  If the parent is sending multiple messages to the child (not a single message to child, single response from child — you can do that much more simply), then some variant on TLV is necessary so you know how much data to read.  At a pinch, you can use an 'end marker' for each message, but you need to be careful.

Comment: If your messages are shorter than the size of the pipe buffer (which is between 4 KiB and 64 KiB), then you can write complete messages atomically. If they're longer than the buffer, you have to make multiple reads to get all the data.  If the messages are short and the protocol is synchronous (so the parent won't send a new message to the child before the child has responded to the previous message), then you can have the child read big chunks, and know it'll get the whole message. Your code shows a single write/read cycle — your child could simply read to EOF (if the parent closes the pipe).

Answer (score 0):

From the moment you call `fork`, you can be sure that everything written on the pipe will be read by the child process:

- If the parent writes something and the child doesn't read it immediately, it will stay in the pipe buffer until the child reads.
- If the child starts reading before the parent starts writing then the `read` of the child will block until there's something to be read.

You might want to `close(p[1])` after writing to it in the parent, so that the child can correctly recognize the end of the data. This is not a problem in your specific case since you write a fixed amount of data and read the exact same amount, but in general it is best to close a pipe after writing to it.

There's not really much to worry about. The only thing that would be better if you have a really long string is to read and write in chunks and process each chunk separately in the children, so that your program doesn't use too much memory to keep something it doesn't need.

Also, side note: when you use string literals `"like this"`, you don't have to add the NUL terminator `\0`, it is automatically added.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible that the child starts reading in the pipe BEFORE that the parent has finished writing in it?

This isn't a concern. [`read(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) call block until there's something to read unless you mark the file descriptor as non-blocking.

> How can I make sure that all the message will be read without reading char by char and looping while there are chars?

The thing is pipes don't understand what a "message" is or its start or end; it's just stream of bytes passed from one end to another. Read [`pipe(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) for details.

If you have any "start", "end", "length" markers, then you need to construct/deconstruct yourself. You can always *ask* `read(2)` more and if returns short of what's asked, you can conclude that's all there is (while checking the return value and `errno` to know the exact reason for that: end-of-file, I/O error, etc).